# Zeros of multivariables polynomials over algebraically closed fields extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am trying to prove that if two algebraically closed fields, $F$ and $K$ such that $K$ contains $F$, J is ideal in $F[x_1,...,x_n]$, and $f$ is a polynomial in $K[x_1,...,x_n]$ that vanishes on Z(J) *with respect to $F$* (i.e, if $(a_1,..,a_n)$ in $F^n$ vanishes every $g$ in $J$ than it vanishes $f$), than $f$ vanishes on $Z(J)$ with respect to $K$.
Everything I tried got me to a dead end. 
I'll be glad for some help with this one

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ vanishes on $Z(J)$ with respect to $F$, then by Nullstellensatz, since $F$ is algebraically closed, $f^n\in J$ for some $n$. Hence $f$ vanishes on $Z(J)$ with respect to any field $K$ containing $F$ (algebraically closed or not).

**Edit:** It was pointed out to me that $f$ is in $K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$.
In that case, I believe the solution goes as follows: (editing this on my phone at a layover, will edit to format properly later)

Let $I$ be the radical of $J$.
By Nullstellensatz, we have the exact sequence
$$ 0\to I\to F[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\overset{\mathbf{ev}}{\to} F^{V(J)}.$$
Tensoring with $K$ over $F$ (noting that $F$ is a field, so $K$ is flat), we get
$$0\to KI\to K[x_1,\ldots, x_n]\overset{\mathbf{ev}\otimes K}{\to} K^{V(J)}$$
Then if $f$ vanishes on $V(J)$ then by definition, it lies in the kernel of the evaluation map, and hence $f\in KI$. $KI$ is the radical of $KJ$, so $f^n$ is in $KJ$ for some $n$, and thus $f$ vanishes on $V(J)$ with respect to $K$. This solution doesn't require $K$ to be algebraically closed.

Comment: Howcome? f is not a polynomial with coefficients in F. And we know f vanishes over the roots of J only in F^n

Comment: @S.Co ah I misread the question, thanks! I'm about to fly, I'll edit later.